# Using python 'requests' package to sort by date

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to follow the justice.gov API documentation page [here](https://www.justice.gov/developer/api-documentation/api_v1), but am unfamiliar with how this notation works while using the python package "requests". I want to read in the most recent press releases, and am trying to sort by date.

I use requests in the following way.

```
url = 'http://www.justice.gov/api/v1/press_releases.json?pagesize=10'
fraud = requests.get(url, proxies = proxyDict )
```

How can I sort by date, or call from a specific date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the parameters they document are URL query parameters. Just pass those to `requests` via the `params` argument, see [*Passing Parameters In URLs*](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```
params = {
    "pagesize": 10,
    "sort": "date",
    "direction": "DESC",
}
url = "https://www.justice.gov/api/v1/press_releases.json"
response = requests.get(url, params=params, proxies=proxyDict)
# either check `response.ok` is true or use `response.raise_for_status()
results = response.json()
```

Note that I didn't use the `?...` part in the URL, leave that to `requests` to worry about.

The API mentions the concept of filtering by parameter value; put those in the `params` dictionary *with* the `parameters[...]` text and square brackets; e.g. to filter on data for a specific value for the `number` field, use:

```
params = {
    "parameters[number]" = "09-007",
    ...
}
```

or, assigning to an existing dictionary:

```
params["parameters[number]"] = "09-007"
```

For the `components` and `topics` lists, the API appears to expect the UUIDs, not the titles, of the associated values.

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> params = {
...     "pagesize": 10,
...     "sort": "date",
...     "direction": "DESC",
... }
>>> url = "https://www.justice.gov/api/v1/press_releases.json"
>>> response = requests.get(url, params=params)
>>> response = results.json()
>>> pprint(results['metadata'])
{'executionTime': 3.1876049041748047,
 'responseInfo': {'developerMessage': 'OK', 'status': 200},
 'resultset': {'count': 144582, 'page': 0, 'pagesize': 10}}
>>> len(results['results'])
10
>>> pprint(results['results'][0])
{'attachment': [],
 'body': '<p>Indianapolis – United States Attorney Josh J. Minkler announced '
         'today that his office has launched a review of all polling places in '
         'the Southern District of Indiana to determine if they are in '
         'compliance with the Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA) of 1990. '
         'The initiative is in accordance with the federal government’s '
         'congressionally-mandated responsibility to review compliance with '
         'the ADA. It is not in response to any specific complaint against a '
         'county or individual polling location.</p>\n'
         '\n'
         '<p>“This year marks the 30th anniversary of the Americans with '
         'Disabilities Act. Indiana counties have had more than enough time to '
         'ensure that their polling places provide full access to individuals '
         'with disabilities,” said Minkler “Hoosiers in the Southern District '
         'of Indiana, that have a disability, deserve equal access to polling '
         'places and we are committed to making sure that they have it in time '
         'for the 2020 election.”</p>\n'
         '\n'
         '<p>As part of the review, election officials in Indiana’s southern '
         'sixty counties are being asked to complete survey questions '
         'pertaining to polling place accessibility in their county. '
         'Investigators may then conduct on-site inspections to confirm survey '
         'responses and to evaluate compliance with federal ADA regulations. '
         'Counties found to be non-compliant will have the option of resolving '
         'issues informally, and if that effort fails, entering into a '
         'Voluntary Compliance Agreement with the government, whereby they '
         'voluntarily agree to upgrade their facilities, and address issues in '
         'order to meet ADA requirements before the November 2020 '
         'election.</p>\n'
         '\n'
         '<p>Counties found to be engaging in a pattern or practice of '
         'discrimination, or that fail to enter into Voluntary Compliance '
         'Agreements, may face a civil lawsuit brought by the government '
         'and/or be subject to penalties, including monetary penalties and '
         'civil fines.</p>\n'
         '\n'
         '<p>The ADA prohibits discrimination on the basis of disability in '
         'all programs, activities, and services provided by public entities. '
         'The ADA requires that public entities provide voting facilities that '
         'are accessible to people with disabilities.</p>\n'
         '\n'
         '<p>Any citizen with polling place concerns in the Southern District '
         'of Indiana is encouraged to contact Assistant United States Attorney '
         'Jeffrey D. Preston, Civil Rights Coordinator, at 317-226-6333.</p>\n'
         '\n'
         '<p>In October 2017, United States Attorney Josh J. Minkler announced '
         'a Strategic Plan designed to shape and strengthen the District’s '
         'response to its most significant challenges. This initiative '
         'demonstrates the office’s firm commitment to maintaining a robust '
         'program of promoting and enforcing federal civil rights laws. '
         '<i>See</i> United States Attorney’s Office, Southern District of '
         'Indiana <a href="/usao-sdin/StrategicPlan"><u>Strategic '
         'Plan</u></a>\xa0Section 7.3 and 7.4.</p>\n',
 'changed': '1583499835',
 'component': [{'name': 'Civil Rights - Voting Section',
                'uuid': 'cbd106d8-8b13-4d1a-9cd6-3fe4f57e39cf'},
               {'name': 'USAO - Indiana, Southern',
                'uuid': 'f5b4046c-2959-4854-807d-abfc65233e4f'}],
 'created': '1583499810',
 'date': '1583470800',
 'image': [],
 'number': None,
 'teaser': None,
 'title': 'United States Attorney’s Office launches review of Indiana polling '
          'places for compliance with the Americans with Disabilities Act',
 'topic': [],
 'url': 'https://www.justice.gov/usao-sdin/pr/united-states-attorney-s-office-launches-review-indiana-polling-places-compliance',
 'uuid': 'f3cacf9f-e7da-4b18-aaa1-645ccec191af',
 'vuuid': 'd3b2876d-d3ee-4075-8c19-556dee053e46'}
```

Comment: Thak you for the dictionary notation. I changed "title" to "date" and "ASC" to "DESC", but the order of the results is still returning articles from Feb 2000.

Comment: @shakebeforeopening: I'll take a look, but this is very much what their documentation states should work.

Comment: @shakebeforeopening: ah, I did make a copy-pasta error: it's `"direction"`, not `"string direction"` (I accidentally copied along the type information in the docs).